# Using IBM Bockchain to store data

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger

I would like to  have a webpage to take input from a user, do the encoding and store the data in the IBM Blockchain. Can you please let me know how can the values from the webpage be passed on to the chaincode?

I am trying to implement KYC with IBM Blockchain. Are there any tutorials or demos to demonstrate this. I have referred https://github.com/IBMBlockchain/marbles/blob/master/docs/tutorial_part1.md.

Is there any other simpler reference?

Comment: Way too broad. SO is for solving small, reproducible programming issues.

Comment: What is KYC? What are your data requirements?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at the Fabric v1.0 examples.  There is an example of how to utilize Node SDK to write data to the blockchain. I am assuming you can figure out how to get the webpage data to Node environment.

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/write_first_app.html